# Integral of Elliptic Function giving Period

Tags: complex-analysis, elliptic-functions

I am working on the following problem that was [previously posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3483760/proving-a-result-regarding-period-of-elliptic-functions/3483785#3483785) regarding the integral of an elliptic function. I understand the entire solution that was posted; however, there is a small piece of the puzzle that I do not understand.

We have shown that $S(0)-S(\infty)=\int_{\partial\mathcal{F}}z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$, and we wish to show that this is a period of $f$ that is we wish to show that it is an element of the lattice. I note that

$$\int_{\partial\mathcal{F}}z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=\int_a^{a+\omega_1}z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz+\int_{a+\omega_1}^{a+\omega_1+\omega_2}z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz+\int_{a+\omega_1+\omega_2}^{a+\omega_2}z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz+\int_{a+\omega_2}^az\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz$$

Now using the periodicity of $f$ we have that
$$
\int_a^{a+\omega_1}(z+\omega_2)\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=\int_{a+\omega_2}^{a+\omega_1+\omega_2}z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz
$$
and
$$
\int_a^{a+\omega_2}(z+\omega_1)\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz=\int_{a+\omega_2}^{a+\omega_1+\omega_2}z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz
$$
Thus, when we simplify make this substitution we should arrive at
$$
S(0)-S(\infty)=-\omega_1\int_a^{a+\omega_1}z\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz-\omega_2\int_a^{a+\omega_2}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz
$$
The place I am getting stuck is I want to show that both of these integrals are integers as that would let us conclude the result, and I think it might be some application of the residue theorem, but these are not closed curves, so I am stuck at this last step, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: First, a comment to the prior question: you might want to recall the [argument principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle).  Second, to your question here: You don't evaluate just these two integrals.  Draw the four intervals of integration -- you want a path that encircles the zeroes and poles in the positive direction, so what signs do you need to assign to these four integrals to get a path in the positive direction?

Comment: $$\int_a^{a+\omega_2}\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz =\log f(a+\omega)-\log f(a)= 2i\pi k$$ with $k\in \Bbb{Z}$ and $\log f$ a primitive on the line $a+\omega t$. The other integral has no $z$.